# Spreadsheet Upload

Tags: c#, excel, upload

Getting a weird problem when uploading a spreadsheet via C#.

Here's an example of the spreadsheet I'm using:

```
JournalISSN
-----------
1650327
223956
1651781
9254927
3064530
9209964
924977X <- this is causing an error
3768716
```

My upload code (snipped for brevity)

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source="
            + Server.MapPath("/admin/journals/upload.xls") + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";

        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

using (DbCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                Command.CommandText = "SELECT [JournalISSN], JournalTitle, JournalDescription, ImpactFactor, Psychology "
                    + "FROM [Sheet1$]";

using (DbDataReader DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader())
{
     while (DataReader.Read())
     {
           Response.Write(string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataReader["JournalISSN"].ToString()) + "<br/>");
      }
}
```

Now what happens, is when the DataReader gets to the row with the "X" in the "JournalISSN" column, it returns True (so it's null/ empty), all other columns return false. So the problem seems to be that whenever a column contains a character that is not numeric, it does not get pulled out during the upload.

A few things i've tried:

- Moving the 'X' to different positions in the text (ie. 111X111)
- Changing to a different letter
- Deleting the cell and starting again
- Setting the format type in excel to "General" - applied on all rows.

Would be grateful for any help/ insight as to why this is happening.

Cheers, Sean

Comment: Have you tried formatting the cells as Text?

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld - yup just tried that, still returns the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find luck in changing the connection string to include the `IMEX=1` extened property. Using the IMEX=1 will force ADO to treat each column as a string instead of attempting to idenitfy the data type. You can find more details [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel).

Comment: thank you so much for this! It works perfectly now. Do you know why this happens? It's almost like it's reading the first row as numeric, so treating any rows after that with the same datatype...